# Paste a URL in terminal using bash script on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, paste

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I need to write a Bash script which would automatically paste a URL to the terminal without having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on the keyboard.

The script contains the command:

```
wget -O "url"
```

The URL would already be copied before the script executes.

Comment: What operating system should this work on? What desktop environment / window manager are you running?

Comment: Iam using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The windows manager is compiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can install xsel (`sudo apt-get install xsel` if not installed) and use:

```
wget -O $(xsel --clipboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have these two aliases to help me out in this kind of situation:

```
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'
alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
```

Then you can do things like:

```
wget -O $(pbpaste)
```

or

```
awk "/UG/ {print \$2}" <<(route -n) | pbcopy
```